# SQL code to generate next sequence in a alphanumeric string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some string values already populated in a nvarchar column. the format of the strings are like this:

For example: 16B, 23G, 128F, 128M etc...

I need to find out the maximum value from these, then generate the next one from code. The logic for picking up the maximum item is like the following:

1. Pick up the string with the largest number.
2. If multiple largest number, then pick up the string the largest alphabet among those.

For example, the largest string from the above series is 128M.

Now I need to generate the next sequence. the next string will have

1. The same number as the largest one, but alphabet incremented by 1. I.E. 128N
2. If the alphabet reaches to Z, then the number gets incremented by 1, and alphabet is A.
   for example, the next String of 128Z is 129A.

Can anyone let me know what kind of SQL can get me the desired string.

Comment: So, is it SQL Server or Oracle? And what5 have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi RedFilter, this is sql server 2008. I tried to use max(columnName). but it does not find the maximum value correctly. it is wrongly detecting that 2E is bigger than 10S.

Comment: Is the number always at the beginning? Is the string always one character max? Are there ever more than one number or character sequences in a given value?

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you could change the table definition to store the letters and number in separate columns (or in fact, just a numeric column) and a computed column that creates this hybrid value.

Comment: Hi Redfilter, yes the numbers are always at the beginning and the letters are always 1 character. there are only one Number-Alphabet sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    ([Value] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    ([Value])
VALUES
    ('16B'),
    ('23G'),
    ('128F'),
    ('128M')
;
```

You can do:

```
select top 1 
    case when SequenceChar = 'Z' then
        cast((SequenceNum + 1) as varchar) + 'A'
    else
        cast(SequenceNum as varchar) + char(ascii(SequenceChar) + 1)
    end as NextSequence
from (
    select Value, 
        cast(substring(Value, 1, CharIndex - 1) as int) as SequenceNum, 
        substring(Value, CharIndex, len(Value)) as SequenceChar
    from (
        select Value, patindex('%[A-Z]%', Value) as CharIndex
        from MyTable
    ) a
) b
order by SequenceNum desc, SequenceChar desc
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0cbb/33)

Comment: Thank you redfilter, this works fine (after a slight modification due to an error Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.)

Comment: @ManasSaha What was the data that caused the issue? I would like to update my query.

Answer (score 5):

If you can change the table definition(*), keeping the basic values entirely numeric and just formatting into these strings would be easier:

```
create table T (
    CoreValue int not null,
    DisplayValue as CONVERT(varchar(10),(CoreValue / 26)+1) + CHAR(ASCII('A') + (CoreValue-1) % 26)
)
go
insert into T (CoreValue)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.object_id)
from sys.objects so1,sys.objects so2
go
select * from T
```

Results:

```
CoreValue   DisplayValue
----------- ------------
1           1A
2           1B
3           1C
4           1D
5           1E
6           1F
....
22          1V
23          1W
24          1X
25          1Y
26          2Z
27          2A
28          2B
29          2C
....
9593        369Y
9594        370Z
9595        370A
9596        370B
9597        370C
9598        370D
9599        370E
9600        370F
9601        370G
9602        370H
9603        370I
9604        370J
```

So inserting a new value *is* as simple as taking the `MAX` from the column and adding 1 (assuming serializable isolation or similar, to deal with multiple users)

---

(*) Even if you can't change your table definition - I'd still generate this table. You can then join it to the original table and can use it to perform a simple `MAX` against an `int` column, then add one and look up the next alphanumeric value to be used. Just populate it with as many values as you ever expect to use.

Comment: Without having to change the original table this could be used as a lookup to find the next value in the sequence. +1

Comment: @Tony - I just realised that and was editing my question to mention that possibility :-)

Comment: Hi damien, thanks for your help, but changing the table schema is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: @ManasSaha - As myself and Tony point out though, you can create the above table and use it as a lookup table - lookup alphanumeric -> int, MAX(), add 1, lookup int -> alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column always follows the format you described (number+1 char suffix), you can do

```
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT LEFT(your_column,LEN(your_column)-1) as num, 
RIGHT(your_column,1) as suffix
FROM your_table),
cte2 AS (SELECT MAX(num) as max_num FROM cte1)
SELECT 
 CASE c.max_suffix
  WHEN 'Z' THEN 'A'
  ELSE NCHAR(UNICODE(c.max_suffix)+1)
 END as next_suffix,

CASE c.max_suffix
 WHEN 'Z' THEN a.max_num+1
 ELSE a.max_num
END as next_num

FROM  cte2 a 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(suffix) as max_suffix FROM cte1 b WHERE b.num=a.max_num)c
;
```

I'm pretty sure there are other ways to do the same; also, my approach doesn't seem optimal, but I think it returns what you need...

No doubt it would be much better if you can redesign the table as **Damien_The_Unbeliever** recommends.

Answer (score 0):

To generate alphanumeric String sequence in below format.
A B C.....Y Z AA AB......AZ BA BB.....BZ...go on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_az(in_num  number)

RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

 num          PLS_INTEGER    := TRUNC (in_num) - 1;
 return_txt     VARCHAR2 (1) := CHR (65 + MOD (num, 26));

BEGIN

 IF  num <= 25
 THEN
      RETURN     return_txt;
 ELSE
      RETURN     to_az (FLOOR (num / 26))
           || return_txt;
 END IF;
END to_az;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ms-sql function to generate an alpha-numeric next sequence id like 'P0001','P0002' and so on.

```
ALTER FUNCTION NextProductID()
 returns varchar(20)
 BEGIN
    DECLARE  @NEXTNUMBER INT;
    DECLARE @NEXTPRODUCTID VARCHAR(20);
 SELECT @NEXTNUMBER=MAX( CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(PRODUCT_CODE,2,LEN(PRODUCT_CODE))))+1 FROM Product;
    --PRINT @NEXTNUMBER;
    SET @NEXTPRODUCTID=CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NEXTNUMBER)
    SELECT @NEXTPRODUCTID='P'+REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(@NEXTPRODUCTID)) + @NEXTPRODUCTID;
  return @NEXTPRODUCTID;
END
```

Here product is the table name and product_code is the column